# Spaces added to occurrences of "{}" in the TeX code

Tags: spacing, macros

Can anyone explain how to get rid of spaces that are automatically added around arguments provided in curly braces in the main part of a text? Here's a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}

\newcommand{\oldtext}[1]{}
% \newcommand{\oldtext}[1]{\sout{#1}}

\begin{document}
There is absolute no doubt {} {} {} {} that the difference between $x=3$ and $x=4$ shall 
not be ignored. After all, $3$ and $4$ are different numbers. 
So why in the world would \oldtext{anybody} \oldtext{somebody} anyone argue for that?

\end{document}
```

The result is:

[image: Example output]

As it can be seen, the repeated occurrences of "{}" add spaces. The "\oldtext" macro shows why this can be problematic in practice. It is used here to denote old text for which it should be possible to be made visible when needed later (by exchanging the definition of the oldtext macro). Of course, the last line of the main part of the text could be written as:

```
So why in the world would\oldtext{anybody}\oldtext{somebody} anyone argue for that?
```

but this is hard to read in the code, confuses the version control software, and would require to add a space inside the macro oldtext to avoid the old texts being stitched together, which is kind-of-ugly. Also, spaces before or after \oldtext can easily be overlooked during proof-reading of a document.

Ideally, I would like to replace the command "\newcommand{\oldtext}[1]{}" by some expression that behaves like "\relax" rather than "{\relax}".

Comment: The design is actually that `{}` should provide for extra space, if not prevented by `{\ignorespaces}` or as in Bordaigorl's answer with `\@bsphack\@esphack` way.

Comment: `{}` does _not_ add any space. The spaces are the explicit spaces in your source file.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle but when I simply write "no doubt <many spaces> that the" instead of "no doubt {} {} {} {} that the", the words "doubt" and "that" are correctly spaced. So while the "{}" themselves may not add the spaces, their presence adds them (to the visual output in the compiled PDF/PS file).

Comment: @DCTLib yes but `doubt {} that` has two spaces in the output for exactly the same reason that `doubt ? that` has two spaces. The extra space is nothing to do with `{}` two adjacent space characters produce a single space token in tex's scanner, and in neither case are there any adjacent spaces, while in `doubt  that` there are two adjacent space characters which are tokenised to a single space token.

Comment: @DCTLib you have to think of `{}` as an (empty) word, so LaTeX processes it as needing separation from the surrounding words. Does this help? In fact `bla{}bla` does not insert any space between the two `bla`s

Comment: Note that neither answer is "preventing `{}` add space", they are stopping the following ` ` produce space. The space in the output comes from the space in the input, not from `{}`.

Comment: You have a number of possible use cases, e.g., `a \oldtext{b} c\par
a \oldtext{b}c\par
a\oldtext{b} c\par
a \oldtext{b} \oldtext{b} c\par
a\oldtext{b} \oldtext{b} c\par
a \oldtext{b}\oldtext{b} c\par
a \oldtext{b} \oldtext{b}c\par
a\oldtext{b}\oldtext{b} c\par
a \oldtext{b}\oldtext{b}c\par
a\oldtext{b}\oldtext{b}c\par`.  Depending on your goal for each of these cases determines the best choice.  One choice not given below in the answers that guarantees **exactly one space** in all cases is `\newcommand{\oldtext}[1]{\unskip\ \ignorespaces}`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Another general answer that solves the problem:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\oldtext}[1]{\@bsphack\@esphack}
\makeatother
```

while `\ignorespaces` always eats up all the spaces `\@bsphack\@esphack` check if a space is needed in some cases:
when there is a space after the command but not before

```
hi\oldtext{bla} there.
```

In this case the `\ignorespaces` solution would give

```
hithere.
```

while the `\@bsphack` one would correctly insert the space between the two words:

```
hi there.
```

This is the solution used by LaTeX's macros that do not typeset stuff like `\label`.

Answer (score 6):

Use `\ignorespaces` inside of the empty `{}` pair. The difference between using and not using it is shown by the two macros `\oldtext` and `\evenoldertext`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}


\newcommand{\oldtext}[1]{\ignorespaces}

\newcommand{\evenoldertext}[1]{}


% \newcommand{\oldtext}[1]{\sout{#1}}

\begin{document}
There is absolute no doubt {} {} {} {} that the difference between $x=3$ and $x=4$ shall 
not be ignored. After all, $3$ and $4$ are different numbers. 
So why in the world would \oldtext{anybody} \oldtext{somebody} anyone \evenoldertext{Hello} argue for that?

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Will mark as solved if nobody points of a drawback of this approach in the next 24 hours or so.

Comment: @DCTLib in my solution I give a different answer and its advantages over `\ignorespaces`

Comment: @Bordaigorl I've seen it - it does require the definition of oldtext to be inside a custom package, however (due to the @s in the code), unless I am mistaken here.

Comment: @DCTLib no that's not necessary, just use `\makeatletter` and `makeatother` as I did, it can stay in your preamble.

Comment: there's extra space showing between "anyone" and "argue".  the example would be more convincing if `\evenoldertext` were used consistently in the second string.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: A typo...

Comment: The solution is good.  But the drawback is that one must remember to use `a \oldtext{b} c` or `a \oldtext{b}c` rather  than `a\oldtext{b} c`.